# Apache Flink: Best Practice

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I have a few questions regarding apache flink.

1. I have reference data stored in multiple relational database, I can get them via restapi.
   These data are static and only need to be loaded once. And it meant to be shared by all flink operators. What should I do here, Can I just load it within my flink job.
2. Does it make sense to have flink parallelism > kafka partitions. What do we gain here? I am assuming flink will automatically pass data from partitions and rebalance and redistributed to more threads for computation. So the gain is mainly on computation part, but the speed for sourcing cannot be improved because it is strictly binded by how many partitions you have in kafka.

Comment: For (1), I assume Flink has some broadcast operation similar to Spark maybe? Otherwise,, use something Debezium to get data into Kafka instead of REST. For (2), you're correct, you're limited to the number of partitions for Kafka consumption

Comment: 1: Do you want every parallel instance to have all of this static enrichment data, or should it be partitioned in some way? (And if so, partitioned how?) 2: Your assumption isn't correct, but Flink will rebalance or repartition the data if you implement your job to do that. As for flink parallelism > kafka partitions, the answer depends on several factors you haven't told us about.